# Send a XMPP message to an OpenFire room from the command line

Tags: c#, command-line, xmpp, openfire

I'm having problems trying to send an XMPP message to a 'Room' in our OpenFire instance. The end result is for our CruiseControl.NET build server to be able to send success/failure messages to the appropriate 'Rooms' as an additional means of notification.

I'm using the Matrix XMPP library to create a Console Application in C# using VS2010. The idea was to create a simple .exe that I can wire up to CCNet and pass a few arguments into as required.

The code below is basically the sample code from the Matrix site/documentation which I have updated to point to a room.

```c#
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var xmppClient = new XmppClient
    {
        XmppDomain = "SERVER",
        Username = "davidc",
        Password = "*********"
    };

    xmppClient.OnRosterEnd += delegate
    {
        xmppClient.Send(new Message
        {
            To = "roomname@conference.SERVER",
            From = "davidc@SERVER",
            Type = MessageType.groupchat,
            Body = "Just Testing the XMPP SDK"
        });
    };
    xmppClient.Open();

    Console.WriteLine("Press return key to exit the application");
    Console.ReadLine();

    xmppClient.Close();
}
```

I can send to an individual user (changing the To and Type accordingly) without any problems but changing the code to point to a room ends in silence! Is there some additional 'handshaking' that needs to be done to address a room?

I don't really have to use C# for the solution as long as it will run on a Windows Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to read [XEP-0045](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html), "Multi-User Chat".  You need to enter the room before sending a message to it.  For a quick fix, see section 7.1.1, which shows how to join a room using a simplified (older) protocol:

```
<presence
    to='darkcave@chat.shakespeare.lit/thirdwitch'/>
```

For the newer protocol, include an extra `x` tag from section 7.1.2:

```
<presence
    to='darkcave@chat.shakespeare.lit/thirdwitch'>
  <x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'/>
</presence>
```

I don't know your library, but you'll want code something like:

```
xmppClient.Send(new Presence
{
    To = "roomname@conference.SERVER/mynick",
});
```

Comment: Thanks Joe - I did take a look at the Multi-User chat section but being an XMPP virgin it lost me a little. If I'm in the right place then I'll roll my sleeves up and try again ;-)

Comment: I've tried sending a new Presence object just before the message but no joy - do you have any code?

Comment: Thanks Joe - finally got it sorted